# Calcular o preço total da coluna com ng repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou tentando fazer uma soma na coluna de preços totais, mas ela não é atualizada à medida que você pesquisa, o valor mantém a soma total e não dos itens que estão mostrando.

```
angular.forEach($scope.receivables, function (item) {
  $scope.valueTotalReceivable += item.price++;
  return $scope.valueTotalReceivable;
});
```

Gostaria de mostrar os valores atualizados da coluna de preço total enquanto procuro.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi com esse alteração:

```
    $scope.totalIncome = function (filteredArrayIncome) {
      let total = 0
      for (let i = 0; i < filteredArrayIncome.length; i++) {
        const sum = filteredArrayIncome[i]
        total += parseFloat(sum.service_price)
      }
      return total
    }
```

Se alguém tiver uma resposta melhor, ficarei agradecido. :)